# Call function on each array indexs value

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array which looks like this

```js
 arcAxis:
0:{x: 1.2858791391047208e-15, y: 21}
1:{x: -21, y: 21.000000000000004}
2:{x: -35.8492424049175, y: 6.150757595082504}
3:{x: -39.40038395815852, y: -14.546812157640753}
4:{x: -32.12697787933814, y: -34.24700413672001}
5:{x: -16.811252024253655, y: -48.61462542668643}
6:{x: 3.0355856977321465, y: -55.47779032614515}
```

Now I have a function which draws elements using x and y of arcAxis.

What I want to do is to call that function to draw an element for each of arcAxis's index value something like this

```js
function test() {
  plot(0. x, 0. y)
}
.....

function test() {
  plot(6. x, 6. y)
}
```

So, that I have 6 new elements made on different x,y values respective to their indexes

my approach is printing each element 6 times then printing next element 6 times

```js
function test() {
  const arcAxis = this.spiral();
  for (var z in arcAxis) {
    plot(arcAxis[z].x, arcAxis[z].x)

  }
}
```

Anyway, can I print each element only 1 time with only 1 indexes value?

Comment: Unsure what you mean with your last question "anyway i can print each element only 1 time with only 1 indexes value?". Do you have ONE array with SIX elements, or SIX arrays with SIX elements?

If you have only one array, you can plot its elements 6 times if you wish, but you will plot 6 times the same elements.

Comment: @minitauros Hi, what i want to do is take the 0th indexs value plot 1st element regarding those values, then take 1st indexes value and plot 2nd element regarding those value.

Comment: What about a simple `for()` loop? E.g `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { plot(arr[(i + 1)]); }` (small example because I cannot do newlines in a comment, but hopefully you get the gist). In my example I use the element at index `i + 1`, which is not the current, but the next element.

Comment: @minitauros Hi i tried using for loop. Its printing 1st element 6 times then 2nd one 6 times and so on

Comment: Still unclear what you mean then. Is your `plot()` function printing it 6 times? Because the for loop in my example should only print 6 things and then trigger an index out of range error.

Maybe an example of all your code and where you think it goes wrong?

Comment: You should edit your answer to clarify your starting data. And also clarify your intent. Currently it's nor really clear.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data= {
  arcAxis:[
   {x: 1.2858791391047208e-15, y: 21},
   {x: -21, y: 21.000000000000004},
   {x: -35.8492424049175, y: 6.150757595082504},
   {x: -39.40038395815852, y: -14.546812157640753},
   {x: -32.12697787933814, y: -34.24700413672001},
   {x: -16.811252024253655, y: -48.61462542668643},
   {x: 3.0355856977321465, y: -55.47779032614515}
  ]
 }
 
 data.arcAxis.forEach(({x, y})=>{ 
   plot(x,y);
 })
 
function plot(x,y){
  console.log("X: ", x,"Y: ", y );
}
```

Comment: Nice usage of object destructuring.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a pre EcmaScript 6 version:

```
arcAxis.forEach(function(element) {
    plot(element.x, element.y);
});
```

And for EcmaScript 6 and onwards:

```
arcAxis.forEach(element => plot(element.x, element.y));
```

[image]

Comment: hi I tried ur way, but its printing each element at only the last x and ys value